# Shorter regex for color strings

Tags: javascript, regex, hex, rgb

Replacing color strings from a `box-shadow` computed value or a style rule is quite the hustle. Found something out there but I need something shorter.

```
// extract a hex color with a space before or after
// test string "1px 1px #555 inset" OR "1px 1px #555"
var color1 = "1px 1px #555 inset"; // OR "1px 1px #555"
var hex = color1.match(/(\s+\#+([a-f0-9]{6}|[a-f0-9]{3})|\#+([a-f0-9]{6}|[a-f0-9]{3})+\s)/ig);

// also extract a rgb/rgba with a space before or after
var color2 = "rgb(150,160,155) 1px 2px"; // OR "1px 2px rgb(150,160,155) inset"
var rgb = color2.match(/(rgb|rgba)+\([^)]+\)+\s|\s+(rgb|rgba)+\([^)]+\)/g);
```

As you can see, both look really long, they work almost fine though.

UPDATE: as requested, I will add more info on what I'm expecting from this regex. Here the test cases:

- `1px 1px #555` - from this string I need the color with the space before, exactly so `' #555'`
- `1px 1px #555 inset` - from this string I need the color with spaces before and after, exactly so `' #555 '`
- `1px 1px rgb(150,150, 150)` - from this string I need the color with space before, exactly like so `' rgb(150,150, 150)'`
- `1px 1px rgb(150,150, 150) inset` - from this string I need the color with space before and after, exactly so `' rgb(150,150, 150) '`
- `rgb(150,150, 150) 1px 1px` - from this string I need the color with space after, exactly `'rgb(150,150, 150) '`

I hope this is clear now. So is there a way to have them shorter as well as checking for all explained above?

Comment: are you sure about your first regex? it matches `######345fff111 ` which looks a bit weird to me

Comment: I didn't think we would actually have that kind of hex value. Still, is a `\#{1}+` gonna fix that?

Comment: If you want a single `#` then `#` is enough (like `#([a-f0-9]{6}|[a-f0-9]{3}`)

Comment: if you only want to match # followed by 3 or 6 hex chars in the first example `#(?:[a-f\d]{3}){1,2}\b` should be enough

Comment: Why do you want to do this?

Comment: @torazaburo I need to process each value separately.

Comment: Not convinced regex is the best approach here.

Comment: @DaveNewton it's best I can actually do for now, still, why you feel that way?

Comment: Because the required regex is almost impossible to reason about. By contrast, this would be handled by a fairly simple grammar.

Comment: I agree, however, that doesn't always work best, how would you do it then?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could merge the two patterns into one:

```js
// extract a hex color with a space before or after
// test string  OR "1px 1px #555"
var color1 = "1px 1px #555 inset"; // OR "1px 1px #555"
// also extract a rgb/rgba with a space before or after
var color2 = "rgb(150,160,155) 1px 2px"; // OR "1px 2px rgb(150,160,155)"
var color3 = "rgb(0, 0, 0) 15px 15px 6px 0px inset";
var p = /(\s?(?:#(?:[\da-f]{3}){1,2}|rgba?\(\d{1,3},\s*\d{1,3},\s*\d{1,3}\))\s?)/gi;
var rgb1 = color1.match(p);
var rgb2 = color2.match(p);
var rgb3 = color3.match(p);
document.write(rgb1 + "</br>");
document.write(rgb2 + "</br>");
document.write(rgb3);
```

**UPDATE2** To match a rgb or rgba color correctly, you would need to use a longer pattern. Hope someone can come up with a better version than the following one:

```
/(\s?(?:rgb\((?:(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|1[0-9][0-9]|[1-9][0-9]|[0-9]),\s*){2}(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|1[0-9][0-9]|[1-9][0-9]|[0-9])\)|rgba\((?:(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|1[0-9][0-9]|[1-9][0-9]|[0-9]),\s*){3}(?:0(\.[0-9])?|1|1.0)\))\s?)/gi
```

**REGEX EXPLANATION**

```
(               #capturing group starts
\s?             #match 0 or 1 space
(?:             #1st non-capturing group starts
rgb\(           #match rgb( literally
(?:             #2nd non-capturing group starts     
(?:             #3nd non-capturing group starts
25[0-5]|        #match 250 to 255, OR
2[0-4][0-9]|    #match 200 to 249, OR
1[0-9][0-9]|    #match 100 to 199, OR
[1-9][0-9]|     #match 10 to 99, OR
[0-9]           #match 0 to 9
)               #3rd non-capturing group ends
,               #match comma (,) literally
\s*             # match 0 or more spaces
)               #2nd non-capturing group ends
{2}             #repeat pattern 2 times for rgb
(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|1[0-9][0-9]|[1-9][0-9]|[0-9])
                #same pattern as above but no comma(,) or spaces             
\)              #match ) literally
|               #OR
rgba\(          #match rgba( literally
(?:(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|1[0-9][0-9]|[1-9][0-9]|[0-9]),\s*)
                #same pattern as 2nd non-capturing group
{3}             #repeat pattern 3 times for rgba
(?:             #6th non-capturing group starts
0(\.[0-9])?|    #match 0.0 to 0.9 for the last value, OR
1|1.0           #match 1 or 1.0 for the last value  
)               #6th non-capturing group ends           
\)              #match ) literally
)               #1st non-capturing group ends
\s?             #match 0 or 1 space
)               #capturing group ends
```

[REGEX 101 Demo](https://regex101.com/r/uW0hN1/5)

Comment: Wow, that looks neat, let me give it a try.

Comment: Ok that doesn't work, try it against `rgb(0, 0, 0) 15px 15px 6px 0px inset`

Comment: @thednp: That's because there is space inside `rgb(0, 0, 0)`. Now it's okay.

Comment: Still doesn't work as I need it, please make sure the regex also include a space before, after and both. The code I have in my question still works better despite the fact that's terrible looking.

Comment: the pattern also matches incorrect rgb strings, such as `rgb(0, 0)`, `rgb(150,160,155,100,11,100)` . But it should not

Comment: Thank you. This works as expected now. I wish I could mark this answer as well. I will think about it.

Comment: @thednp: Just feel free to mark the question you like. I'd be happy if the answer helps.

Comment: Have to say `/(\s?(?:#(?:[\da-f]{3}){1,2}|rgba?\(\d{1,3},\s*\d{1,3},\s*\d{1,3}\))\s?)/gi` works perfect, I tested with most cases, I will mark your answer, it's great.

Comment: @thednp according to https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/CSS/color_value which was posted to my answer, rgba needs 4 values, which isn't covered here at all, furthermore rgba(0,0,0,0) will fail. Also this one will actually allow rgb(999,999,999) - i wonder why you accept this, after being so nitpicking on my attempts and accusing me of being too dumb to understand your question.

Comment: @ccf your answer is perfectly fine for OPs question, have an upvote :)

Comment: @SebastianProske: Thanks for that. I updated the rgb color pattern so that it could match rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) also. But it's still not perfect. To make it not to match rgba(0, 0, 0) and rgb(0, 0, 0, 0), the pattern would be even longer.

Comment: @ccf Sorry but the last value for rgba is between 0.0 and 1.0, not between 0 and 255

Comment: @SebastianProske: You are right. It's my mistake for overlooking the last value. Hopefully the new pattern works. By the way, it's a pity that js regex does not support named group.

Answer (score 1):

I tried to simplify your regex a bit, putting it all into a single pattern:

```
/#(?:[\da-f]{3}){1,2}\b|rgba?\([\d, ]+\)/ig
```

Imo you don't really have to check for a space or anything to start, as `rgb`/`rgba`/`#` seem to be clear enough. Also there shouldn't be a reason to check for the space behind in the case of `rgb()` as it always finishes with a bracket.

- `#(?:[\da-f]{3}){1,2}\b` will match the `#` followed by three hex chars once or twice (so 3 or 6 in total) and a word boundarie (space, end of string, komma - anything but letters, numbers or underscore)
- `rgba?\([\d, ]+\)` will match rgb or rgba followed by an opening bracket, that contains more than one number or comma or space and a closing bracket

Take a look at https://regex101.com/r/aA3aW2/1 for a set of samples.

If you want them to be seperate patterns, you could easily split them up again to

```
/#(?:[\da-f]{3}){1,2}\b/ig
/rgba?\([\d, ]+\)/ig
```

If however you want to keep spaces, you need to change the patterns to

```
/\s?(?:#(?:[\da-f]{3}){1,2}\b|rgba?\([\d, ]+\))\s?/ig
/\s?#(?:[\da-f]{3}){1,2}\b\s?/ig
/\s?rgba?\([\d, ]+\)\s?/ig
```

Edit:
As you also want to verify a correct format, the regex has to be a lot longer, to take care of this, here is what i got right now:

```
/\s?(?:#(?:[\da-f]{3}){1,2}\b|rgb\((?:(?:[01]?\d?\d|2[0-4]\d|25[0-5]),\s*){2}(?:[01]?\d?\d|2[0-4]\d|25[0-5])\s*\)|rgba\((?:(?:[01]?\d?\d|2[0-4]\d|25[0-5]),\s*){3}(?:0(?:\.\d+)?|1(?:\.0+)?)\s*\))\s?/ig
```

See https://regex101.com/r/aA3aW2/2 for the updated sample set.

Comment: This doesn't check for space before, after or both, so my code in the question is still better. I need a regex that works the same.

Comment: the pattern also matches incorrect rgb strings, such as `rgb(0, 0)`, `rgb(150,160,155,100,11) `. But it should not

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest if that is a requirement for the OP, i can change the pattern, but it will add complexity, especially if you want to check for numbers from 0 to 255 and 0 to 1 for the a-value

Comment: @SebastianProske as the above comment say, the `rgb` regex should match both `rgb` | `rgba` and always a properly formatted color. The regex should work with both `window.getComputedStyle(element,null).boxShadow` which is always `rgb(0, 0, 0) 0px 0px 0px 0px inset` format AND a style rule like `1px 1px #069` | `1px 1px solid #069 inset`. So I won't test your solution until you fully understand the requirement.

Comment: @SebastianProske, it's not only a requirement for the OP, it's also a requirement of Functional Notation rgb(R,G,B) and rgba(). https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/CSS/color_value

Comment: @thendp you should edit this into your question, making clear what you actually require, adding positive and negative examples. I'm sorry, but I'm not your student.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out, let me edit the question real quick, I don't want any more negative votes.

Comment: @SebastianProske sorry to bother, I edited the question, hope it's crystal clear now, please check.

Comment: @thednp are leading 0 allowed for the rgb values (like 007,007,007). Anyways there is no way to keep the regex shorter than you original approach, but i can give you thousands of false positives it matches. Maybe you want to take a short look at https://regex101.com/r/aA3aW2/2

Comment: Yes, that looks efficient, however, still long, perhaps there's no shorter solution after all. Thank you so much. I will mark your question. UPDATE: I also tested and it works as expected.